# add + button before a row

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can i add green + button before a row in group table see in image

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.row == 1)//type your condition here

    {   
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    else{

        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    } 

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        //type your code here
    }else if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert){

           //type your code here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this sample code link
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ListAdder/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010275

Comment: thanx this gives solution but it is little bit typical.